# I need values from database to dynamically appending combobox using jquery in codeigniter

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

Given below is my code to append a row which includes textbox and combobox
  to which i need to load values from database(I need to load values into      combobox).Here is the jquery code to append a row.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
     $('#button').on('click', function(){
        $('.tablesaw').find('tbody').append($('<tr><td><select id="heard" class="form-control" name = "fieldname[]"><option value="0">-- Choose --</option><option value = "1">Amount</option></select></td><td><input type  = "text" name = "condition[]" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12"></td><td><select id="heard" class="form-control" name = "unit_head[]"><option>--Choose--</option><option value = "10">sabith</option><option value = "11">Nizar</option></select></td></tr>'));
        $('.e1').select2();
        $('.e2').select2().on('change', function () {
        $(this).next()
            .find('.select2-selection')
            .css({ backgroundColor: this.value });
        }).trigger('change');
    });
});
</script>
```

Here is the code written in controller

```
public function get_unit_heads()
{
    $this->load->model('unit_model');
    $data = $this->unit_model->get_unit_heads();
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

Here is the code written in model

```
public function get_unit_heads()
{
    $sql="SELECT emp_id,name FROM employee";
    $query=$this->db->query($sql);
    $result=$query->result_array();
    return $result;
}
```

Please help me to load these database value into dynamically appending combobox

Answer (score 0):

Use ajax() to get the data from database and pass in the `val()` attribute of textbox in which you want the data to be shown.

Ex:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax_function_url',                        
        type: 'POST',                                  
        data: {
            var1  :val1,    // parameters in key : value pair
            var2  :val2
        },
        success: function(response){    // response from server
            // code to pass response values into val() attribute
        }
    });
});
```

**Note:** Don't forget to include jquery library in your code

Comment: Inside $('#button').on('click', function(){  **Make ajax call and get the response and set it to val()** });